# Reference for MANOVA or multivariate mixed models

Tags: references, manova

What is the go-to reference to understand both the theory behind MANOVA, or multivariate linear mixed models in general, and to understand application?

I can find R-vignettes lying around the web, but isn't there a proper book that teaches it from scratch?

My current issue is modelling a multivariate response vector, in a linear model, using both random effects and main effects (discrete + continuous).

Comment: This seems to be off topic here.

Comment: There's a tag called "references"? It's also a specific topic, so I don't think  answers are going to be like "I prefer this book out of these 20 alternatives", but rather "here are the 2-3 main classics".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't many books dedicated specifically to MANOVA, one which gets good reviews on amazon is [Applied MANOVA and Discriminant Analysis] by Huberty & Olejnik.  If you want a book with the mathematical details, you would need a book on theoretical multivariate analysis like [Rencher](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470178965) (one chapter) or [T W Anderson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8126524480).